# DateTime from SQL when read in C# gets reduced by 1 sec

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server, datetime

Here is a portion of my c# code

```
try
{
    Database db = DatabaseFactory.CreateDatabase();

    string sqlCommand = Constants.GET_UPDATE_STATUS; ;
    DbCommand dbCommandWrapper = db.GetStoredProcCommand(sqlCommand);

    db.AddParameter(
        dbCommandWrapper,
        "@p_CurrentUpdatedUTCTime",
        DbType.DateTime2,
        ParameterDirection.InputOutput,
        null,
        DataRowVersion.Current,
        _myDateTime);

    db.AddOutParameter(dbCommandWrapper, "@p_UpdateStatus", DbType.Int16, 10);
    db.ExecuteNonQuery(dbCommandWrapper);
    status = 
      Convert.ToInt16(db.GetParameterValue(dbCommandWrapper, "@p_UpdateStatus"));
    currentUpdatedUTC = 
      db.GetParameterValue(dbCommandWrapper, "@p_CurrentUpdatedUTCTime").ToString();
}
catch (Exception exp)
{
    errorMessage = exp.Message;
    throw new DataAccessException(exp.Message, "UpdateStatusDAL", "GetUpdateStatus", exp);
}
```

In the above code `currentUpdatedUTC` is the datetime which i'm reading as out from SQL.
Its works fine but there is a difference of 1 sec in the time read from SQL.
For example if i execute the SQL procedure it outputs

`2014-01-28T06:49:29`

But when i read it from C# i get

`2014-01-28T06:49:28`

Here is the SQL stored procedure parameters

`@p_UpdateStatus  SMALLINT OUTPUT,
@p_CurrentUpdatedUTCTime DATETIME OUTPUT`

Comment: are the milliseconds being stored?  They could be rounding the seconds up.

Comment: even if they are, it should be passed out into c# part rite?

Comment: depends on the precision.  see this article for an explaination:
http://milesquaretech.com/Blog/post/2011/09/12/DateTime-vs-DateTime2-SQL-is-Rounding-My-999-Milliseconds!.aspx

Comment: The syntax of SQL is such that, at any particular point when you encounter a name, the form of the name or the position it's in will immediately inform you on what type of object is being named. There is thus *really* no reason to use prefixes, suffixes, or anything else to distinguish object types in SQL. (names vs views is the notable exception, but as much as possible, you should be treating views identically to tables anyway)

Answer (score 0):

You define the parameter as `DbType.DateTime2`, but in the stored procedure you are using `DATETIME`, which has a lower precision.  Rounding may be occurring.

Try using a `DATETIME2` in your stored procedure and the underlying SQL table.

Also, I don't think you are telling us the whole story, because neither SQL Management Studio or the default `.ToString()` output uses the ISO format (with the `T` in the result).  Perhaps you could edit your question to show the real output.